# Proj4text from 5.2 to 7.0+

Tags: gis, postgis, proj

I have extended the PostGIS plugin in my postgres database and customized the coordinate reference system(srid=38599). Its proj4Text is:

```
+proj=pipeline +step +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=114 +k=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6356752.314 +units=m +no_defs +step +proj=helmert +convention=coordinate_frame +x=-74.45 +y=-339.8231 +s=1.0009 +theta=34.82
```

(old Proj version is 5.2). How should I transform this proj4Text into a form supported by the current version now? (For example, changing to Proj version 7.0+).

I am trying to turn it into this form in the new version：

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=114 +k=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6356752.314 +units=m +no_defs +to +towgs84=-74.45,-339.8231,0,0,0,34.82,1.0009
```

However, executing the same function operation(st_transfrom function) as the old version resulted in inconsistent results. I have tried Google, but unfortunately I couldn't find a solution. Can someone help me?